# angular call gettiing cancled after 30 sec

Tags: php, angular, laravel-5.5

I have write a code to chunk upload file to AWS server using laravel and dropzone, but i am facing wired problem. after 30 sec my angular get canceled. I have already set PHP parameter to max. here it is.

```
post_max_size = 200M
max_execution_time = 360
max_input_time = 120
memory_limit = 128M
```

This is my PHP(Laravel code)

```
$aws=Storage::disk('s3');
    $receiver = new FileReceiver("media", $request, HandlerFactory::classFromRequest($request));
        if ($receiver->isUploaded() ) {
            // receive the file
            $save = $receiver->receive();
            // check if the upload has finished (in chunk mode it will send smaller files)
            if ($save->isFinished()  === true) {
                // save the file and return any response you need
                /*print_r($save->getFile());
                exit;*/
                return $aws->put($files->getClientOriginalName(),file_get_contents($save->getFile()),'public');
            } else {
                // we are in chunk mode, lets send the current progress
                /** @var AbstractHandler $handler */
                $handler = $save->handler();
                return response()->json([
                    "done" => $handler->getPercentageDone(),
                ]);
            }
        } else {
            throw new UploadMissingFileException();
        }
```

And this is my dropzone setting.

```
this.dropzoneConfig ={ 
        url : environment.apiurl+'/project/driveupload/?section=1&projectid='+this.projectId,
        acceptedFiles:"audio/*",
        autoReset:1,
        chunking: true,
        paramName: 'media',
        maxFilesize: 400000000,
        chunkSize:4000000
    };
```

can someone help to solve this issue? is there some setting in angular too, which i have to set?

**PS: I am using laravel 5.5, and angular 4**

[image: angular call Call]

Answer (score 0):

I've solve my error by changing setting in dropzone.

```
this.dropzoneConfig ={ 
        url : environment.apiurl+'/project/driveupload/?section=1&projectid='+this.projectId,
        acceptedFiles:"audio/*",
        autoReset:1,
        chunking: true,
        paramName: 'media',
        maxFilesize: 400000000,
        chunkSize:4000000,
        timeout:400000000 // increased time in millisecond.  
    }
```